# How can I create a list from a part of an existing list on Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list with 6899 numbers, from wich I have to create a new list containing only te terms from i=3200 to i=4121. Kind of like a copy and paste.

I tried the following:

```
e = a[3200<i<4121]
```

Being "e" the new list and "a" the original one, but this code returns a float, instead of a new list, any hints?

Comment: See [The Python Slice Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `slice` notation:

```
e = a[3200:4121]
```

There's also an optional `step` parameter:

```
e = a[3200:4121:1]
```

which is completely equivalent to the above, but you could use that form to get (for example) every other element starting at index 3200 and ending at index 4121 (not inclusive):

```
e = a[3200:4121:2]
```

Note that the "start" parameter is **inclusive**, but the "stop" parameter is **exclusive**.  So,  `lst[n:m]` will give you a list staring at index slice out indices `n` to `m-1`.

Comment: The term for the third parameter is `step`. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice